# Salesforce rest api v49 requests fail

Tags: salesforce

The calls work on the salesforce api version 48.0 fail on the version 49.0 with not found error.

For example if I make a get request to 'https://yourinstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Opportunity/describe'
works perfectly fine, but
when I make a get request to
'https://yourinstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Opportunity/describe'
it fails with not found error.

Did the structure of the call changed?
Was the endpoint deprecated? If so could you please point me to the right page in the changelog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...you do realise that v49 is Summer'20 release and that's not live yet?

You can make a call to `https://instancename.my.salesforce.com/services/data/` to see versions ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_versions.htm)), it'll end with something like

```
<Versions>
...
<Version>
     <label>Winter '20</label>
     <url>/services/data/v47.0</url>
     <version>47.0</version>
</Version>
<Version>
     <label>Spring '20</label>
     <url>/services/data/v48.0</url>
     <version>48.0</version>
</Version>
</Versions>
```

Summer'20 release is in preview in certain sandboxes: https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2020/05/summer-20-sandbox-preview.html

Some productions (and sandboxes on non-preview instance) will get the release on July 11th weekend, last ones will be upgraded on July 18th. You can also check it on https://status.salesforce.com/instances/UM5/maintenances (put your instance in the url if you know it or you can use the search for the "My Domain" version)